# React Transition Group - i dont understand it well

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, transition, react-transition-group

I'm trying to make an array of images that changes image every few seconds.

I made it change randomly and now I'm trying to add transition so it so it will look prettier.

The only way I saw it's being possible with React is using react-transition-group.

so I have made this `useEffect`:

```
const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState(image1);
  const inProp = useRef(true);

  const defaultStyle = {
    transition: `opacity 2s ease-in-out`,
    opacity: 0,
  };

  const transitionStyles = {
    entering: { opacity: 1 },
    entered: { opacity: 1 },
    exiting: { opacity: 0 },
    exited: { opacity: 0 },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const changeImage = () => {
      const imagesArr = [image1, image2, image3];
      const imagesLength = imagesArr.length;
      let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesLength);
      setImageSrc(imagesArr[random]);
      inProp.current = !inProp.current;
    };

    setInterval(changeImage, 6000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(changeImage);
    };
  }, []);
```

```
     <Transition in={inProp.current} timeout={300}>
                {(state) => (
                  <img
                    src={imageSrc}
                    alt="about-img"
                    className="about-img"
                    style={{
                      ...defaultStyle,
                      ...transitionStyles[state],
                    }}
                  />
                )}
              </Transition>
```

also I get this kind of error:

[image]

so what happens now it makes transition but not the way I want it.
I want to make the transition on every change of image.
maybe you guys can please help me?
Thanks alot !

Answer (score 0):

It is probable that you are using `React.StrictMode`. [Here](https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack/issues/345) a work-around is presented by the removal of `StrictMode`, however, that should only be tried if all else fails.

The [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#warning-about-deprecated-finddomnode-usage) proposes adding refs. [Here](https://medium.com/trabe/getting-rid-of-finddomnode-method-in-your-react-application-a0d7093b2660) we can see an example for it:

```
import React, { createRef, Component } from "react";

// ChildComponent uses React.forwardRef to obtain the ref passed to it
// and then forward it to the DOM div that it renders.
const ChildComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) =>
  <div ref={ref}>
    <span>{props.children}</span>
  </div>
);


class MyComponent extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
      const node = this.childRef.current;
      /* Uses DOM node  */ 
  }

  childRef = createRef();

  render () {
    return (
        // Pass the created ref to ChildComponent
        <ChildComponent ref={this.childRef}>{this.props.children}</ChildComponent>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

So, we:

- `import` `createRef`
- instantiate it
- add a `ref` attribute to the component's markup pointing to `this.childRef`

Comment: hi, thanks for your comment. i didnt quite understand how to solve this problem. and this error is minor for now, im just trying to change the images with transition effect.

Comment: @YardenYosef you can either `createRef` and assign it to the `ref` attribute or remove `StrictMode`.